# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vertical') - PDF VIEWER

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, ng2-pdf-viewer

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vertical') at appendText.
Version using -

```
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "^7.0.1"
```

I'm getting this error while viewing a pdf. I've implemented pdf viewer inside a modal and while user click on view button this modal will appear. I've got the result and I can view it but getting this error on my console.

How can I handle this situation.